# Disable objectStorage in Gitlab Toolbox Chart

Tags: charts, gitlab, k3s

I use the official [Gitlab Toolbox Chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/charts/gitlab/toolbox/) in K3S and want to to store the [generated backup](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/backup-restore/backup.html#create-the-backup) in [K3S default `local-path`](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/storage/).

This is my config.

```
toolbox:
  enabled: true
  replicas: 1
  backups:
    cron:
      enabled: true
      concurrencyPolicy: Replace
      persistence:
        enabled: false
        accessMode: 'ReadWriteOnce'
        size: '50Gi'
      schedule: '0 1 * * *'
  persistence:
    storageClass: 'local-path'
    enabled: true
    accessMode: 'ReadWriteOnce'
    size: '50Gi'
```

And this is the output of `kubectl exec <Toolbox pod name> -it -- backup-utility`.

```
2022-05-17 06:40:57 +0000 -- Dumping repositories ... done
Dumping registry ...
empty
Dumping uploads ...
done
Dumping artifacts ...
empty
Dumping lfs ...
empty
Dumping packages ...
empty
Dumping external_diffs ...
empty
Dumping terraform_state ...
empty
Dumping pages ...
empty
Packing up backup tar
[DONE] Backup can be found at s3://gitlab-backups/1652769629_2022_05_17_14.10.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar
```

For some reason the toolbox still uses `s3` as storage and I am not able to access the `backup` in the `local-path` even though a toolbox volume gets created.
Does anybody know how to disable the `objectStorage` in Gitlab Toolbox and save the backup in `local-path`?

Comment: How did you solve this? As far as I understand, toolbox only uploads to s3... ?!

Comment: I did not solve this. Indeed.